# Microsoft Office require administrator credentials on first run

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-office-2013

I install Microsoft Office 2010 or 2013 on a new computer.
I launch Word or Excel from the Administrator account. I am then asked to choose if I want to use the recommended settings. I accept, and the question is never asked again for this account.

[image: First things first]

When a new user log into the computer and run Word/Excel/Whatever, this very same question is asked about the recommended settings.
The problem is: the user must provide administrator credentials to validate his choice. Else the user can't run the software.

I see I can [disable this screen](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/odsupport/2012/11/13/how-to-manage-the-opt-in-or-first-things-first-prompt-when-microsoft-office-2013-applications-are-first-launched/).
But I'd like to know if/how I can disable the need to provide administrator credentials.

Comment: how about disabling it via registry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you posted the [answer](http://blogs.technet.com/b/odsupport/archive/2012/11/13/how-to-manage-the-opt_2d00_in-or-first-things-first-prompt-when-microsoft-office-2013-applications-are-first-launched.aspx) in your original post.  This is a task best suited to GPO.  As the article you reference mentions, you need to download the [Office 2013 Admin Templates](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35554).  In my situation I copied the appropriate .adxm and .adml files from the extracted templates.  You can then copy them into `%WINDIR%\SYSVOL\domain\Policies\PolicyDefinitions` (.adml is a language based template and can be placed in the appropriate folder, i.e. 'en-us'.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [User Account Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) (UAC) escalation dialog.
There is no way to avoid it, except by [disabling UAC](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-user-account-control-uac-the-easy-way-on-windows-vista/).
If there are several users on your computer, this might not be prudent
as it will in effect give all of them administrator powers.

I don't know exactly why Windows brings up time and again this dialog
for new users. But as all you do is accept the recommended settings,
meaning that Windows updates are to be done automatically,
you can use [the link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/odsupport/archive/2012/11/13/how-to-manage-the-opt_2d00_in-or-first-things-first-prompt-when-microsoft-office-2013-applications-are-first-launched.aspx) you have found to turn off the dialog.

In a normal situation, Windows Update should keep on functioning in the
background without that dialog.
Just in case, you had better verify at least once,
within a couple of days after the next [Patch Tuesday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_Tuesday),
that the updates were in fact done.

Answer (score -1):

I can't exactly say that it will work, but you can try this:

> 1. Press ***Ctrl + R*** to open the run box and type ***"regedit"***
> 2. Now navigate to
>
> **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion >
>   Policies > System**
>
> 3. Now, double-click on ***EnableLUA*** and set its ***Value Data = 0*** and click on OK.
> 4. Restart your machine if prompted to do so.

Comment: This is disabling UAC.

Comment: looks like its the best option

Answer (score -1):

Right click the shortcuts/links and ensure that they aren't set to use compatibility mode or run as administrator

Answer (score -1):

How to solve:

1) Try clicking ask me later and accept.

2) Goto control panel and give that user admin rights.

3) Launch office and select what you want (Do this on ALL office programs)

4) Go to control panel and take away that user's admin rights.

5) When launching office on that user. It should work